# How can I retrieve the values of parent as well as child using the same getValue(user.class) method from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the data from parent as well as child node at the same time in my model class. Say for example:

```
Students: {
      Student1: {
            id: 1,
            name: "Sam",
            regNo: "15001"
              1stSmester: {
                      c: 70,
                     dataStructures:80,
                      },
              2ndSemester: {
                        CPlus:85,
                        sql:68
                      }
                 }
      Student2: {
              id:2,
              name:"Rob",
              regNo:"15002"
                1stSemester: {
                       c:59,
                      dataStructures:77
                         },
                 2ndSemester: {
                        CPlus:60,
                        sql: 85
                          }
                  }
```

So, my question is how do I retrieve all the data from student1 and student2? So, its parents values as well as 1stSemester and 2ndSemester child values as 2 separate objects and map it to my own model class.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your data structure seems to go against Firebase's best practices of keeping the data model flat. Given that and the broadness of the question, I recommend you study the [Firebase documentation for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) and take the [codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/)

Comment: Yes, I shall do that. But can you show me how I can make the above data structure flat? I am new to firebase so I don't have much knowlegde of that. And also, in my app I have to  take the student as one object and display it in recyclerView. Can I still do that with flat data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make student and semester class

```
class Students {
int id;
String name, regNo;
Semester semester1, semester2;

 public Semester getSemester1() {
    return semester1;
    }
   ...
}
 class Semester {
    String courseName;
    double result;
}
```

**UPDATE**

inner class has to be declared outside and setters and getters have to be set for inner class objects.

call for data

```
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Students")
    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
    ArrayList<Student> allStudents=
  (ArrayList<Student>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
    }

   @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

    }
    });
    }
```

Comment: I have tried your code but how to retrieve of inner object of firebase. I tried with getters but it shows value 0.

Comment: Did u gave getter setter in the inner class?

Comment: I have tried your code but you have declare the sub classes as outer class. Because if you make inner classes, it shows databaseException. Otherwise its all ok.

Comment: yeah, I got it. The problem was you have to declare the inner classes as outer classes and you have to set getters and setters for the class object too. I have updated answer. please review it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library in order to deserialize your models. I imagine your model in something like this:

```
Class Student{
  int id,regNo; 
  String name;
  Semester 1stSemester;
  Semester 2ndSemester;

class Semester{
    int c;
    int CPlus;
    int sql;
    int dataStructures;
    } 
}
```

then in your code use:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(yourResponse,Student.class);
```

Comment: Can you show how you'd get `yourResponse` from a Firebase `DataSnapshot`?

Comment: i think you can try using getValue, since it returns object, then cast it to string

Comment: @Rahim I don't really understand your Gson code, can I really do tha? How can I use gson in getValue() as getValue take only one argument.

Comment: @RahimRahimli: that won't work. The `DataSnapshot.toString()` unfortunately doesn't return JSON, and `Object.toString()` is anyone's guess.

Comment: what about `String yourResponse = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue()`

Comment: I have tried with sahadat's example and json is also retrieving but i can't use the inner object values. can anyone tell me the solution?